Meraki API - Wireless SSID apTagsAndVlanIds
I'm fairly new to using Python but I'm trying to get the Meraki API to update the apTagsAndVlanIds=[{'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2'], 'vlanId': 100}] parameter so that I can code multiple tags and vlan entries into it.
What I am trying to achieve is some sort of loop that will cycle through a list of entries to build up the apTagsAndVlanIds parameter between the {} but I'm stuck when using append or '+' because the 'tags' variable is expecting a string value and vlanId variable is expecting an integer value.
For example;
ap_tags = [501, 502, 503]
tags_vlans=""

for TAVI in ap_tags:
    tags_vlans = tags_vlans + {'tags': ('Vlan_'+str(TAVI)), 'vlanId': TAVI}

!-- It's here that I'm stuck trying to append or combine the new entry with the existing. The first iteration works a treat.
dashboard.wireless.updateNetworkWirelessSsid(
    network_id, 0, 
    name = 'my_ssid', 
    useVlanTagging = True, 
    defaultVlanId = 500, 
    apTagsAndVlanIds = [tags_vlans],

#where tags_vlans should be
                        {'tags': 'Vlan_501', 'vlanId': 501},
                        {'tags': 'Vlan_502', 'vlanId': 502},
                        {'tags': 'Vlan_503', 'vlanId': 503}
)

Here's the Python error;
tags_vlans = tags_vlans + ({'tags': ('Vlan_'+str(TAVI)), 'vlanId': TAVI},)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Any help or guidance much appreciated.
Have tried the append command, the '+' command, converting the integer to a string none of which seem to work.
